# Haskell postgresql-simple query access single record

Tags: postgresql, haskell, servant, postgresql-simple

In postgresql-simple, the `query` method returns a list.  When I am attempting to access a single record (by pk for example), I know the list should either be empty or a single item.  Is there a canonical way to handle this with postgresql-simple or do I need to layer my own function on top of it?

Currently I do the following with the list returned by `query` to get a single item:

```
  case retrieved of
    [] -> throwError err404
    [r] -> pure r
    (_r : _rs) -> throwError err500
```

For one, the third case will never be hit.  Moreover, this feels like such common pattern that there should be a way to represent it in the type annotation that postgresql-simple requires.

Addendum:

An established pattern for handling this may also extend to operations like delete by pk where we only want a single record to be affected.

Comment: FWIW, I think your code is fine. It's not actually 100% guaranteed that this "never happens", so better be safe than sorry.